# Why Bootstrap 5 Carousel Control Buttons Not Working?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I made a carousel, when I touch these buttons, I want it to go, but it doesn't. How can I do this?

**Code:**

```
<div class="container mt-4">
        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <div class="carousel-indicators">
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1">1</button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2">2</button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3">3</button>
        </div>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/img/black.png" width="100%" height="300px" alt="First slide">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/img/black.png" width="100%" height="300px" alt="Second slide">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/img/black.png" width="100%" height="300px" alt="Third slide">
              </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
              <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: the code doesn't look like youre using BS-5. It's BS4. Kindly update to BS5 https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/carousel/#with-controls or use bs-4 plugin

Comment: its `data-bs-slide`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one that's working copied from the [official documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/introduction/).

```html
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide">
  <div class="carousel-indicators">
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/870/800/400.jpg?hmac=RVmKPEQDqKbI8SLlLbkfaMuxiJVQrPuMoyv7vuxPbL8" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/494/800/400.jpg?hmac=aPwfyKjkUw_ivDNPavHejXC1zg_pSk3LgmPToXqbKOA" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/243/800/400.jpg?hmac=IEsjm30yORWR_y11K0bSLyasctvraSJ_sgNgSNNqQk8" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>
```